# How to set Style Resource to all apps on Wear os using service(Android 9)

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Is it possible to set a style resource file to be active in all apps like via service?

The only piece of code that Is in the XML file is

`<item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>`

listed [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit). Would I need to make a service for this? I am very new to java in android Studio, So I would love anyone to explain like if they are talking to a 5th grader ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your app cannot change any of the resources compiled into other apps.

Comment: There is no way to make a background service with it?

Comment: No, you cannot affect other apps like that.